# Calculating work time and cash

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate time of working and cash earned (lets say its 20 ILS per hour - that's why I am multiplying by 20 in my Application.)

I use `SharedPreferences` so I can get out from the Application and it will still remember when I pressed the start button, also I am using `Calendar.getInstance()` but when I am getting the hours I am using 12 hours format so I will not have problems of calculating working time (if I began in 8am and finished 9pm, working time will be finish minus started, 9-8 and that's one hour so it will be wrong).

I used `INTs` in the beginning but I kept getting zero hours working because you cannot work 0.3 hours in `INTs`, it will cut it to zero, I changed to `Doubles` but surprisingly there is no `getDouble` or `putDouble` in `SharedPreferences` so I switched to `Floats` but I am getting Errors now and my Application crashes.

**Here is my code:**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 0);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting");
            c = Calendar.getInstance();
            begmin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            beghour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putInt("key1", begmin);
            edit.putInt("key2", beghour);
        }
    });
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            finmin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            finhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if (finhour >= beghour)
                workhour = finhour - beghour;
            else
                workhour = 12 - beghour + finhour;
            workmin = finmin - begmin;
            hourcashto = (float)(workhour * 20);
            mincashto = (float)(20 * (workmin / 60));
            cashto = hourcashto + mincashto;
            cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0);
            cash = cash + cashto;
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putFloat("key", cash);
            edit.commit();
            textView.setText("cash now: " + cashto + " cash total including today: " + cash + " \n" + "Time today: " + workhour + ":" + workmin);
        }
    });
}
```

**Here is the Logcat output:**

```
09-01 19:44:19.811  17344-17344/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: firstappdevelopment.work, PID: 17344
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getFloat(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:253)
        at firstappdevelopment.work.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
```

I am sorry if it is half a logcat, I used search for "MainActivity" as there is auto scroll in Android  Studio Logcat and I couldn't get to the crash and copy. The line `MainActivity.java:57 refers to:`

```
cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0);
```

From what I understood, it says cash is an `int` but look at my constructor(?):

```
    private static final String TAG = "ServicesDemo";
private Button buttonStart, buttonStop;
private int begmin, beghour, finmin, finhour, workhour, workmin;
private float cash, cashto, hourcashto, mincashto;
private Calendar c;
private TextView textView;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
```

Thank you all for helping.

**Edit, Full Code+XML**

```
    package firstappdevelopment.work;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "ServicesDemo";
    private Button buttonStart, buttonStop;
    private int begmin, beghour, finmin, finhour, workhour, workmin;
    private float cash, cashto, hourcashto, mincashto;
    private Calendar c;
    private TextView textView;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 0);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting");
                c = Calendar.getInstance();
                begmin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                beghour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putInt("key1", begmin);
                edit.putInt("key2", beghour);
            }
        });
        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping");
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                finmin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                finhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                if (finhour >= beghour)
                    workhour = finhour - beghour;
                else
                    workhour = 12 - beghour + finhour;
                workmin = finmin - begmin;
                hourcashto = (float)(workhour * 20);
                mincashto = (float)(20 * (workmin / 60));
                cashto = hourcashto + mincashto;
                cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0f);
                cash = cash + cashto;
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putFloat("key", cash);
                edit.commit();
                textView.setText("cash now: " + cashto + " cash total including today: " + cash + " \n" + "Time today: " + workhour + ":" + workmin);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="START"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total:"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stop"
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="STOP"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/start"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/start" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you could try `cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0f);` Though not sure if will help

Comment: The error with `getFloat` is probably because you already have an `int` value saved in the `SharedPreferences`. So, when `SharedPreferences` retrieves `"key"`, it loads up an integer, tries to convert it to float and crashes. You could use `int` for 20 minutes, rather than .3 hours. Also, if you want to use `double`, you can store it in `SharedPrefs` as a `String`. You would just have to convert it yourself.

Comment: Also, I would suggest using an `SQLite` database, depending on what all you want your app to be able to do (you could store the hours worked and look up money earned with certain time frames and such). You could probably use [an orm](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+orm&ia=qa) which has a database underneath it and is far simpler to implement than setting up your own DB.

Comment: @Jakar I just want to see how much I worked etc.. there are apps like these outside but I wanted to create myself one, can you take a look at full code and see if it is working for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you know that the problem is here:

```
cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0)
```

I think your code is fine!
But, as you said that you were initially storing some integer value in the shared-preferences for **"key"**. Did you remove those values? 
I will suggest you to try just try to change `cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0)` to `cash = prefs.getFloat("key_new", 0)`. That might be silly issue which you overlooked!

Note, if there is a problem of 0 or 0f or 0.0f in `cash = prefs.getFloat("key_new", 0)`, then it would give you a compile time error.

Comment: ohh.. I think you are right. I will completely delete the app now

Comment: Or just change the key! :)

Comment: Btw, you can also use double by simple storing it as a string [String.valueOf(<your_double_value>)] & if you want to get it just query for the string [getString()] and parse string to double. ;)

Comment: I am close to 15, I will upvote it . I don't know who down voted it and why.

Comment: This answer was correct, but down-voted. Very strange!

Answer (score 1):

So from the error you receive `ClassCastException` you are attempting to pass a default value of `0` from `SharedPreferences` if the value does not exist.

Change `cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0)` to `cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0.0)`

Comment: Then it says it is getting double instead of float - Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'double', required: 'float' less... 

getFloat
(String,
float)
in SharedPreferences cannot be applied
to
(String,
double)
 , should I change it to 0.00000000000000000 :P

Comment: You can cast it like this ("key", (float)0.0) or use the '0f' as @DoomKnight described above.

Comment: Oh actually it is not working, same error, using 0.0f, :|

Comment: tried too, also tried (float)0.0, still not working.. the fact putFloat is after getFloat doesn't matter?...

Comment: I edited with full code, can you see if it is working now?

Comment: if in doubt just set another field of your activity called DEFAULT_VALUE and make it a 0 value float primitive.

Comment: if there is a problem of 0 or 0f or 0.0f in cash = prefs.getFloat("key_new", 0), then it would give you a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
```

your problem is here:

```
cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0);
```

must be:

```
cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0.0f);
```

#### or probably your variable `cash` is defined as int! you have to change to:

```
float cash;
```

More info about [**getFloat()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getFloat%28java.lang.String,%20float%29) method.

Comment: I am sure that this "cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0);" works!

Comment: I don't know why but it is still not working when I am running it, Rebuild my project didn't help.

Comment: @Elenasys It's written specificly how it is defined.

Comment: @Elenasys if that was the case then it would have given the compile time error, rather than run time error.

Answer (score -1):

It is happening because in `prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 0);` 0 is a int. Using 0.0 will solve the problem as it is a float. Corrected code -

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 0.0); // CODE CHANGED HERE
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting");
            c = Calendar.getInstance();
            begmin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            beghour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putInt("key1", begmin);
            edit.putInt("key2", beghour);
        }
    });
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            finmin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            finhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if (finhour >= beghour)
                workhour = finhour - beghour;
            else
                workhour = 12 - beghour + finhour;
            workmin = finmin - begmin;
            hourcashto = (float)(workhour * 20);
            mincashto = (float)(20 * (workmin / 60));
            cashto = hourcashto + mincashto;
            cash = prefs.getFloat("key", 0);
            cash = cash + cashto;
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putFloat("key", cash);
            edit.commit();
            textView.setText("cash now: " + cashto + " cash total including today: " + cash + " \n" + "Time today: " + workhour + ":" + workmin);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If there is a problem of 0 or 0f or 0.0f in cash = prefs.getFloat("key_new", 0), then it would give you a compile time error.